# How to link each div to Vue element, as if one div is parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How Can childDiv be attached only to 'new' variable in childDiv Vue instance, and not with the 'new' variable in parentDiv

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <button v-if="new">New</button>
   <div id="childDiv" v-if="new">This is child div</div>
</div>

<script>
var parentDiv = new Vue({
  el:'#parentDiv',
  data: {
     new: true,
  }
})

var childDiv = new Vue({
  el:'#childDiv',
  data: {
     new: false,
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is never going to work. You'd have to change the variable name. Even then, your first Vue instance is going to complain that, say, `new2` does not exist on the instance but is referenced during render. But the bigger question is: why are you creating a Vue instance inside of another? You should probably use a [component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) instead...

Comment: @Vince I'm new to vuejs, the problem with component is the template who need to be inside the vue, so it make html and script mixed, is there a way to put the template outside vuejs component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think [inline templates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates) may be useful to you here.

Comment: @Vince Yes it is, inline template work for me

Comment: @Vince Can you put your first comment as answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Done ✓. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is never going to work. You'd have to change the variable name. Even then, your first Vue instance is going to complain that, say, `new2` does not exist on the instance but is referenced during render.

But the bigger question is: why are you creating a Vue instance inside of another? You should probably use a [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) instead...

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think [inline templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates) may be useful to you here